# mat-select options became transparent after updating to angular material v7

Tags: angular-material2

I have been working on a web app for the past few weeks and we wanted to make some updates.  We updated the project and all of its node modules and when I got everything working again the select drop down's options were transparent and the mat-cards lost their drop shadow.

Did something change in the material update that made the styles act like this?

[image]

Comment: Are you seeing any console errors when this occurs?

Comment: I don't see any errors in chrome but in Firefox I see a ton of css errors.  I'm not sure if they are related, the most suspect would be 


"Expected ‘none’, URL, or filter function but found ‘alpha(’.  Error in parsing value for ‘filter’.  Declaration dropped"

Comment: I would try deleting your node_modules and repulling packages with `npm install` to see if this issue goes away.

Comment: I gave it a shot, did not work.  I also created a base angular app with ng new test-app and added material, cdk, and animations and put in the mat-select and it is still transparent.

Comment: Can you provide a stackblitz showing the issue?

Comment: I think I figured it out.  I was using metronic template and I think that metronic's material theme broke with the latest update.  I will try to fix this theme.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is caused by using the css files of Material 5/6 with Material 7. 
In my case the css files are imported in index.html from somewhere in /wwwroot/assets/. So upgrading through the cli or package.json was not enough.

In my case the solution was to get the css files of Material 7 from /node_modules/@angular/material/... and overwrite those existing in /wwwroot/assests/.. (these were the old Material 5 css files)

Comment: Thanks for the help. In the end we downgraded until we have the time to fix the css issue.

Answer (score 7):

I updated angular material to 7.2.0 and I noticed the transparent `mat-select-panel`. Adding some css to my global `styles/theme.scss` fixed the issue.

You can add this css to your global root css file or add it to the component css file.

I keep all my angular material css in `styles/theme.scss` file then import it to the component.

Update: I added the prebuilt theme import to my styles/theme.scss file and that pulled in the missing mat-select-panel styles.

```css
 @import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css';
```

```css
.mat-select-panel {
  background: #fff;
}

.mat-select-panel:not([class*=mat-elevation-z]) {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px -1px rgba(0,0,0,.2), 0 4px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.14), 0 1px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.12);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. In my case I had a custom SASS file that imported from `@angular/material/theming`, the application depended on a CSS generated file from this one.

So after upgrading I had to re-generate the CSS file with `node-sass` and `mat-option-panel` wasn't transparent anymore.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue was with me COPY/PASTING/MODIFYING some of the code from the github website in order to begin my approach to styling.

```
/**
 *  The below is what's available in _theming.scss and what I based my code off of.
 * My issue (and I've highlighted the 2 lines, below) was that I had screwed w/ their 
 * comment and slammed the 2 lines together, screwing w/ the mixins in _theming.scss
 */
$mat-light-theme-background: (
  status-bar: map_get($mat-grey, 300),
  app-bar:    map_get($mat-grey, 100),
  background: map_get($mat-grey, 50),
  hover:      rgba(black, 0.04), // TODO(kara): check style with Material Design UX
  card:       white,
  dialog:     white,
  disabled-button: rgba(black, 0.12),
  raised-button: white,
  focused-button: $dark-focused,
  selected-button: map_get($mat-grey, 300),
  selected-disabled-button: map_get($mat-grey, 400),
  disabled-button-toggle: map_get($mat-grey, 200),
  unselected-chip: map_get($mat-grey, 300),
  disabled-list-option: map_get($mat-grey, 200),
);
```

I had modified:

```
  hover:      rgba(black, 0.04), // TODO(kara): check style with Material Design UX
  card:       white,
```

To:

```
  hover:      rgba(black, 0.04), // TODO(kara): check style with Material Design UXcard: white,
```

The result was that the mat-select-panel was not set correctly (nor, I would imagine, was anything else which relied on "card")

Answer (score 0):

In case you are having this issue with more recent version of Material (v16 in my case), don't forget to include theme for `select` elements inside your main theme file:

```
@include mat.select-theme($my-theme);
```